# rotate 3D sphere around itself - webGL

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl

I'm trying to build 3D solar system with webGL.
I have all the stars moving in a circle around the sun as sholud be, and I want them also to spin around their own Y axis.
How can I add it?
I tried :

```
mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(starsList[i].Yangle), [1, 0, 0]);
```

but I got wierd result.
any help?

```
mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0, 0, -30]);

    for (i = 0; i < starsList.length; i++) {  
        mvPushMatrix();
        mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(starsList[i].angle), [0, 1, 0]);
        mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(starsList[i].Yangle), [1, 0, 0]);

        mat4.translate(mvMatrix, starsList[i].initPlace);
        mvPopMatrix(); 
     }


var lastTime = 0;

function animate() {
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    if (lastTime != 0) {
        var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;
        for (i = 0; i < starsList.length; i++) { 
            starsList[i].angle += starsList[i].speed * elapsed;
            starsList[i].Yangle += starsList[i].speed * elapsed;

        }
    }
    lastTime = timeNow;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you don't move each star around the sun using rotation matrix, but rather compute the location using the angle and move each planet to correct location using translation matrix.

Comment: ok, I will think about it, but its still not solve my problem with spin around the Y axis

Comment: [This might be helpful](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-scene-graph.html)

Comment: @john I know, just a tip. Another thing you might want to look into are quaternions. Rotations using only matrices have some problems and caveats, and so many programmers use quaternions for rotations.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(starsList[i].Yangle), [0,1,0]);
```

notice the vector [0, 1, 0], the x value I made 0 and the y value I made 1. I like to think of the vector representing the axis of rotation. There is a lot of useful information found on this [stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724840/is-it-possible-to-rotate-an-object-around-its-own-axis-and-not-around-the-base-c) Additionally, I found this [website](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=239) to be beneficial. (this blog post is about rotating objects so it should come in handy!)

Comment: I think its should be [1 0 0].
and I already check this website but still no success.. I appriciate if you have an answer