# Using theta and phi angles for a rotation in Opengl

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, opengl-es, rotation

I am trying to move and rotate a sphere with OpenGL. For this, I save my matrix state, I load the identity matrix, then I translate to the point that I want and finally, I rotate and push the state as you can see in the above code. Because these procedures are done from the end to the start, the rotation is from (0,0,0) and only after that, it moves to the desired point. Traslation is fine but I have problems with rotations. For this purpose, I wanted to describe the rotations with 2 angles: theta and phi (just following the physics convention that you can see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). If I do first the rotation in phi and then in theta, the result is different from doing in the opposite order. I have understood that this is because of matrix product. Also, I have read that there is a problem with euler angles with gimbal lock and that I should use quaternions but still, I don't have this much clear. I'm viewing my data as an ortho view and because of the above, I am not sure if what I'm doing is correct or it is just some luck that I have with the angles I tried. How would you proceed?

```
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glLoadIdentity();            //I reset the matrix. Now the translation and rotation is from the origin (0,0,0)
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
    gl.glRotatef(theta, 0,1,0); 
    gl.glRotatef(phi, 0,0,1);

    GLUquadric earth = glu.gluNewQuadric();
    glu.gluQuadricTexture(earth, true);
    glu.gluQuadricDrawStyle(earth, GLU.GLU_FILL);
    glu.gluQuadricNormals(earth, GLU.GLU_FLAT);
    glu.gluQuadricOrientation(earth, GLU.GLU_OUTSIDE);          
    glu.gluSphere(earth, radius, slices, stacks);        
    glu.gluDeleteQuadric(earth);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I changed my mind and instead of using ortho, I tried to understand the problem by using perspective. At first, I was noticing like if my particles were rotating an extra angle. But at the end, I think that is because of how is added the texture to the particles. I tried several things like the one said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7725601/1200914 but it was impossible. After trying lots of things, I tried to draw the axis lines and I discovered after lot of hours of tests that I forgot that Math.sin and Math.cos are in radians, not in degrees like OpenGl. When I realised that, I noticed that with lines it was perfect. All is happening from global coordinates. In short:

```
    gl.glRotatef(theta, 0, 1, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(phi, 0, 0, 1);
```

is ok. I let my code that allowed me to understand this. Please, change "ROUTE TO IMAGE" with the route to a png image that is a square divided in 4 different colours (like windows flag). You can make it with paint.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.jogamp.opengl.GL;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;
import com.jogamp.opengl.glu.GLU;
import com.jogamp.opengl.glu.GLUquadric;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.Texture;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.TextureData;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.TextureIO;

/**
 * Test developed using:
 * 
 * A minimal JOGL demo.
 * 
 * @author <a href="mailto:kain@land-of-kain.de">Kai Ruhl</a>
 * @since 26 Feb 2009
 */
public class test3d extends GLCanvas implements GLEventListener {

    /** Serial version UID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** The GL unit (helper class). */
    private GLU glu;

    /** The frames per second setting. */
    private int fps = 24;

    /** The OpenGL animator. */
    private FPSAnimator animator;

    /** The earth texture. */
    private Texture earthTexture;

    private int see_ = 0;

    /**
     * A new mini starter.
     */
    public test3d(int see) {
        addGLEventListener(this);
        see_ = see;
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the screen.
     * 
     * @see javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener#init(javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable)
     */
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        final GL2 gl = (GL2) drawable.getGL();

        // Enable z- (depth) buffer for hidden surface removal. 
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LEQUAL);

        // Enable smooth shading.
        gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);

        // Define "clear" color.
        gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

        // We want a nice perspective.
        gl.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL.GL_NICEST);

        // Create GLU.
        glu = new GLU();
        GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
        // Load earth texture.
        try {
            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(ROUTE TO IMAGE);
            TextureData data = TextureIO.newTextureData(profile, stream, false, "png");
            earthTexture = TextureIO.newTexture(data);
        }
        catch (IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Start animator.
        animator = new FPSAnimator(this, fps);
        animator.start();
    }

    /**
     * The only method that you should implement by yourself.
     * 
     * @see javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener#display(javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable)
     */
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        if (!animator.isAnimating()) {
            return;
        }
        final GL2 gl = (GL2) drawable.getGL();

        // Clear screen.
        gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Set camera.
        setCamera(gl, glu, 30);

        // Prepare light parameters.
        float SHINE_ALL_DIRECTIONS = 1;
        float[] lightPos = {0, 0, 0, SHINE_ALL_DIRECTIONS};
        float[] lightColorAmbient = {1f, 1f, 1f, 1f};
        float[] lightColorSpecular = {1f, 1f, 1f, 1f};

        // Set light parameters.
        gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT1, GL2.GL_POSITION, lightPos, 0);
        gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT1, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, lightColorAmbient, 0);
        gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT1, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, lightColorSpecular, 0);

        // Enable lighting in GL.
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT1);
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHTING);

        // Set material properties.
        float[] rgba = {1f, 0f, 0f};
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialf(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SHININESS, 1f);

        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINES);        //RED == X
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            gl.glVertex3f(10, 0, 0);
        gl.glEnd();

        rgba[0] = 0f;
        rgba[1] = 1f;
        rgba[2] = 0f;
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialf(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SHININESS, 1f);

        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINES);        //GREEN == Y
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 10, 0);
        gl.glEnd();


        rgba[0] = 0f;
        rgba[1] = 0f;
        rgba[2] = 1f;
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialf(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SHININESS, 1f);
        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINES);        //BLUE == Z
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 10);
        gl.glEnd();     

        // Set material properties.
        float theta = 45f;
        float phi = 270f;
        /*
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////LINES 1 ROT//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();            //I reset the matrix. Now the translation and rotation is from the origin (0,0,0)
        rgba[0] = 1f;
        rgba[1] = 0f;
        rgba[2] = 1f;
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialf(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SHININESS, 1f);

        gl.glRotatef(phi, 0, 0, 1);

        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINES);        //VIOLET == X'
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            gl.glVertex3f(10, 0, 0);
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glPopMatrix();


        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();            //I reset the matrix. Now the translation and rotation is from the origin (0,0,0)
        rgba[0] = 1f;
        rgba[1] = 1f;
        rgba[2] = 0f;
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialf(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SHININESS, 1f);

        gl.glRotatef(phi, 0, 0, 1);

        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINES);        //YELLOW == Y'
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 10, 0);
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glPopMatrix();

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();            //I reset the matrix. Now the translation and rotation is from the origin (0,0,0)
        rgba[0] = 0f;
        rgba[1] = 1f;
        rgba[2] = 1f;
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialf(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SHININESS, 1f); 

        gl.glRotatef(phi, 0, 0, 1);

        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINES);        //CYAN == Z'
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 10);
        gl.glEnd();     

        gl.glPopMatrix();
        */

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();            //I reset the matrix. Now the translation and rotation is from the origin (0,0,0)
        rgba[0] = 1f;
        rgba[1] = 1f;
        rgba[2] = 1f;
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialf(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SHININESS, 1f); 

        //gl.glRotatef(theta, (float) Math.sin(phi), (float) Math.cos(phi), 0);
        gl.glTranslatef(3, 0, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(theta, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(phi, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINES);        //WHITE == NEW Y'
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 10.f);
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glPopMatrix();


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////LINES 2 ROT//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();            //I reset the matrix. Now the translation and rotation is from the origin (0,0,0)
        rgba[0] = 1f;
        rgba[1] = 0f;
        rgba[2] = 1f;
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialf(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SHININESS, 1f);

        //gl.glRotatef(theta, (float) -Math.sin(phi), (float) Math.cos(phi),0); 
        //gl.glRotatef(theta, (float) Math.sin(phi*Math.PI/180), (float) Math.cos(phi*Math.PI/180),0);    
        gl.glRotatef(theta, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(phi, 0, 0, 1);

        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINES);        //VIOLET == X'
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            gl.glVertex3f(10, 0, 0);
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glPopMatrix();


        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();            //I reset the matrix. Now the translation and rotation is from the origin (0,0,0)
        rgba[0] = 1f;
        rgba[1] = 1f;
        rgba[2] = 0f;
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialf(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SHININESS, 1f);

        //gl.glRotatef(theta, (float) -Math.sin(phi), (float) Math.cos(phi),0); 
        //gl.glRotatef(theta, (float) Math.sin(phi*Math.PI/180), (float) Math.cos(phi*Math.PI/180),0);    
        gl.glRotatef(theta, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(phi, 0, 0, 1);

        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINES);        //YELLOW == Y'
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 10, 0);
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glPopMatrix();

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();            //I reset the matrix. Now the translation and rotation is from the origin (0,0,0)
        rgba[0] = 0f;
        rgba[1] = 1f;
        rgba[2] = 1f;
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialf(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SHININESS, 1f); 

        //gl.glRotatef(theta, (float) -Math.sin(phi), (float) Math.cos(phi),0); 
        //gl.glRotatef(theta, (float) Math.sin(phi*Math.PI/180), (float) Math.cos(phi*Math.PI/180),0); 
        gl.glRotatef(theta, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(phi, 0, 0, 1);

        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINES);        //CYAN == Z'
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 10);
        gl.glEnd();     

        gl.glPopMatrix();

        //////////////////////////////////////////SPHERES////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Apply texture.

        rgba[0] = 1f;
        rgba[1] = 1f;
        rgba[2] = 1f;
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, rgba, 0);
        gl.glMaterialf(GL.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SHININESS, 1f);

        earthTexture.enable(gl);
        earthTexture.bind(gl);

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();            //I reset the matrix. Now the translation and rotation is from the origin (0,0,0)

        GLUquadric earth = glu.gluNewQuadric();
        glu.gluQuadricTexture(earth, true);
        glu.gluQuadricDrawStyle(earth, GLU.GLU_FILL);
        glu.gluQuadricNormals(earth, GLU.GLU_FLAT);
        glu.gluQuadricOrientation(earth, GLU.GLU_OUTSIDE);          
        glu.gluSphere(earth, 0.5, 64, 64);        
        glu.gluDeleteQuadric(earth);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        earthTexture.disable(gl);

        earthTexture.enable(gl);
        earthTexture.bind(gl);



        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();            //I reset the matrix. Now the translation and rotation is from the origin (0,0,0)
        gl.glTranslatef(1.5f, 0, 0);    
        gl.glRotatef(phi, 0,0,1);

        GLUquadric earth1 = glu.gluNewQuadric();
        glu.gluQuadricTexture(earth1, true);
        glu.gluQuadricDrawStyle(earth1, GLU.GLU_FILL);
        glu.gluQuadricNormals(earth1, GLU.GLU_FLAT);
        glu.gluQuadricOrientation(earth1, GLU.GLU_OUTSIDE);         
        glu.gluSphere(earth1, 0.5, 64, 64);        
        glu.gluDeleteQuadric(earth1);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        earthTexture.disable(gl);

        earthTexture.enable(gl);
        earthTexture.bind(gl);

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();            //I reset the matrix. Now the translation and rotation is from the origin (0,0,0)
        gl.glTranslatef(3.f, 0, 0);         
        gl.glRotatef(theta, 0, 1,0);    
        gl.glRotatef(phi, 0,0,1);

        GLUquadric earth2 = glu.gluNewQuadric();
        glu.gluQuadricTexture(earth2, true);
        glu.gluQuadricDrawStyle(earth2, GLU.GLU_FILL);
        glu.gluQuadricNormals(earth2, GLU.GLU_FLAT);
        glu.gluQuadricOrientation(earth2, GLU.GLU_OUTSIDE);         
        glu.gluSphere(earth2, 0.5, 64, 64);        
        glu.gluDeleteQuadric(earth2);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        earthTexture.disable(gl);
    }

    /**
     * Resizes the screen.
     * 
     * @see javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener#reshape(javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable,
     *      int, int, int, int)
     */
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        final GL gl = drawable.getGL();
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    /**
     * Changing devices is not supported.
     * 
     * @see javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener#displayChanged(javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable,
     *      boolean, boolean)
     */
    public void displayChanged(GLAutoDrawable drawable, boolean modeChanged, boolean deviceChanged) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Changing display is not supported.");
    }

    /**
     * @param gl The GL context.
     * @param glu The GL unit.
     * @param distance The distance from the screen.
     */
    private void setCamera(GL2 gl, GLU glu, float distance) {
        // Change to projection matrix.
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        // Perspective.
        float widthHeightRatio = (float) getWidth() / (float) getHeight();
        glu.gluPerspective(45, widthHeightRatio, 1, 10000);
        if (see_ == 0){
            glu.gluLookAt(10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);        
        }else if (see_ == 1){
            glu.gluLookAt(10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);      
        }else if (see_ == 2){
            glu.gluLookAt(0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);     
        }else if (see_ == 3){
            glu.gluLookAt(0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);     
        }
        // Change back to model view matrix.
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    /**
     * Starts the JOGL mini demo.
     * 
     * @param args Command line args.
     */
    public final static void main(String[] args) {
        GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
        GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);
        capabilities.setRedBits(8);
        capabilities.setBlueBits(8);
        capabilities.setGreenBits(8);
        capabilities.setAlphaBits(8);         

        int size = 640;

        test3d canvas = new test3d(0);        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mini JOGL Demo (breed)");
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setBounds(0, 200, size, size);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        test3d canvas2 = new test3d(1);        
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Mini JOGL Demo (breed)");
        frame2.getContentPane().add(canvas2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame2.setBounds(0, 200, size, size);
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2.setVisible(true);

        test3d canvas3 = new test3d(2);        
        JFrame frame3 = new JFrame("Mini JOGL Demo (breed)");
        frame3.getContentPane().add(canvas3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame3.setBounds(0, 200, size, size);
        frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame3.setVisible(true);

        test3d canvas4 = new test3d(3);        
        JFrame frame4 = new JFrame("Mini JOGL Demo (breed)");
        frame4.getContentPane().add(canvas4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame4.setBounds(0, 200, size, size);
        frame4.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame4.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How i understand, after this rotation gl.glRotatef(theta, 0,1,0) vector (0,0,1) is also changed. For your code gl.glRotatef(phi, 0,0,1) works in object local coordinates. I think you want to do it in global space. I think if you rotate vector (0,0,1) around 0,1,0 to theta degree and use new vector for second rotate.

Here is pseudo code sample:

```
gl.glRotatef(theta, 0,1,0); 
glm::mat4 rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), theta, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
glm::mat4 rotateVector = rotationMatrix * glm::vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
gl.glRotatef(phi, rotateVector.x, rotateVector.y, rotateVector.z);
```

I think this code does not compile. I try to show, what i mean by using [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/index.html) function.